How to isolate item for all aggregatedView
I have combined several models using "aggregatedView".
Viewer.isolate(dibds, model) works normally when loading only one model.
However, if I proceed with "isolate" with multiple models loaded, the new isolation status will be updated and only the last isolate will remain.
When you do it manually, you can isolate it together even with other models, but when you try to use API, isolate is covered and only the last model result value remains.
this.extension.viewer.clearSelection();
for (const [model, dbIds] of dbIdsMap.entries()) {                    
    await this.extension.viewer.isolate(dbIds, model);
    await this.extension.viewer.fitToView(dbIds, model);

    // Change theme color to red
    dbIds.forEach(dbid => {
        model.setThemingColor(dbid, new THREE.Vector4(1, 0, 0, 1)); // Red color
    });
}

I want to know how to isolate multiple models, dbids arrays at once like manually isolate.

It's being looked into and planned to be fixed later on. In the meantime you could stick to a version older than v7.98

Things have been fixed in v7.99 and also a new function was added that makes it easier to isolate in a multi model environment: setAggregateIsolation
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/change_history/changelog_v7/
